# Proving that every reduced residue class contain at least one prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I don't know if I expressed this clearly, but I want to know if the following is true and also some help proving it in case it is.

$\forall a,b \in \mathbb{N} , \gcd{(a,b)} = 1 \Rightarrow \exists  p \equiv b \pmod{a}$

Where $p$ is a prime and $b < a$.

I know the converse is true, because a prime can only be congruent to reduced residue classes.

If it is too trivial, some hints can suffice, if it is not, pointing to good material would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a major theorem. No proof is going to fit here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions

Comment: Highly non-trivial.  this follows from [Dirichlet's Theorem on Primes in Arithmetic Progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)

Comment: it's actually a bit weaker right? Although I don't know if it is easier to prove.

Comment: Yes, I know it is a consequence of Dirichlet's, but I thought that as it only needs one prime, it should be a lot easier. Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: I slept through most of my analytic number theory course, but I'm pretty sure it isn't easier.

Comment: also, the converse is not true, if $a$ is a prime and $b$ is $0$ it is clear that $a\equiv 0\bmod a$ and $a$ is prime.

Comment: @reuns Dirichlet gives an infinity of primes, while OP asks for only one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a$ not a prime

> There are infinitely many primes in $a+q\mathbb{Z}$

is the same as

> for every $K$, there is at least one prime in $\bigcup_{k \ge K} a+kq\mathbb{Z}$"

Thus your statement is equivalent to Dirichlet's theorem in arithmetic progressions.

Comment: Oh yeah, good point.

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions). I don't know a way to prove your theorem without it.